# How can I make an XML File that's constantly updating also update my SQL Tables?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database, filemaker

I'm dealing with a FileMaker Database and a MySQL Database. I've got a script running on a timer that exports the updated FileMaker data in an XML format to a separate IIS server that contains my MySQL database.

I know how to parse the XML into SQL using PHP, but since it's the XML that's constantly being updated, how can I get the Updated XML to not just be constantly added to the database rather just update it?

Also how can I directly parse the XML into SQL Update queries rather than INSERT statements?

Answer (score 2):

Although it is doable, I suggest much easier way. FileMaker can use MYSQL tables directly, so instead of exporting XML just link MYSQL tables to FileMaker and update data directly.

You can look up FileMaker ESS. This should get you started:

https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/16/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help/external-data-sources.html

ODBC is the other way of doing this.